# Jordan basis of $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{T}}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $X:=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}}(A)$. If $\mathcal{S}$ is the basis for which $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S}}(X)$ is the Jordan Canonical Form of $X$, which is the basis $\mathcal{T}$ for which $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{T}}(A)$ is the JCF of $A$?

*My Proof.* Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $J:=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S}}(X)$. We know that
$$A=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B}}(Id)\cdot X\cdot\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B}}(Id)^{-1},$$
$$X=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{E}}(Id)\cdot J\cdot\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{E}}(Id)^{-1}.$$
Therefore, $A=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B}}(Id)\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{E}}(Id)\cdot J\cdot(\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B}}(Id)\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{E}}(Id))^{-1}=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}(Id)\cdot J\cdot\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{S},\mathcal{B}}(Id)^{-1}$.
We conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ is the basis $\mathcal{S}$ written in basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Can you tell me if my proof is correct? Thanks in advance.